# boto3 mturk send_bonus error

Tags: python, django, boto3, mechanicalturk

When I try to send bonus via Boto3 regularly (but not always) the `RequestError` appears:

```
Exception Type: RequestError
Exception Value:    
An error occurred (RequestError) when calling the SendBonus operation: 
This user is not authorized to perform the requested operation.  
Exception Location: /Users/chapkovski/mynewotree/lib/python3.5/site-packages/botocore/client.py in _make_api_call, line 615
```

the code is the following:

```
response = client.send_bonus(
            WorkerId=self.WorkerId,
            BonusAmount=str(form.cleaned_data['bonus_amount']),
            AssignmentId=self.AssignmentId,
            Reason=form.cleaned_data['reason'],
        )
```

Since it works sometimes, it seems that there is a certain maximum amount that can be sent as a bonus per day. I do it in Sandbox so definitely it is not a problem of lack of funds. Anyone else has encountered the similar issue?

UPDATED: I've found the spurce of error: for some strange reasons mTurk doesn't allow to send more than $100 per day per worker.

Comment: Catch it, wait sometime and retry. That is a bit silly, but on the other hands eventual consistency has that kind of drawbacks.

Answer (score 3):

I've found the source of error: for some strange reasons mTurk doesn't allow to send more than $100 per day per worker (that is at least true for Sandbox - did not test with the 'real' endpoint).

Comment: I have sent out bonus higher then $100 in one day to workers